How can I render my HTML page dynamically with SocketIO?
I have been working on an app that parses and renders alarms in the form of a HTML document. I have been using Flask and now I wanted to incorporate SocketIO so that the page manually refreshes when alarm files are loaded, deleted or modified in a folder. The app works and when i delete, add or modify files in my "data" folder and manually refresh the page, the page renders as it should. But my SocketIO emit function that should refresh the page everytime something is added deleted or modified doesn't work. I tried literally everything. What could be the solution?
app.py
import os
import html
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import threading
import time
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask import jsonify
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

data_folder = 'data'

def load_alarms(file_paths):
    alarms = []
    categories = ["parameter=", "short=", "long=", "repair=", "context="]       #separators

    for file_path in file_paths:
        text = open(file_path, "r", encoding='utf-8')
        lines = text.readlines()
        new_lines = []                                      #loading all alarm files and removing unwanted character and empty spaces 
        for line in lines:
            new_lines.append(line.removesuffix('\n'))
            line = line.removesuffix('\n')

        s = ""
        new_text = s.join(new_lines).strip().strip("'").strip('"').split("¤")

        if len(new_text) == 8:
            alarm = {
                'Alarm ID' : new_text[0],
                'Alarm Information' : new_text[1],
                'Parameters' : new_text[2].split(categories[0])[1],
                'Internal Severity' : new_text[3],                          #removing separators and saving information to a dictionary
                'Explanation' : new_text[4].split(categories[1])[1],
                'Long Description' : new_text[5].split(categories[2])[1],
                'Troubleshooting' : new_text[6].split(categories[3])[1],
                'Context' : new_text[7].split(categories[4])[1],
            }
        alarms.append(alarm)
    return alarms

alarms_data = []

def update_alarms_data():
    global alarms_data
    file_paths = [os.path.join(data_folder, f) for f in os.listdir(data_folder) if f.endswith('.txt')]
    alarms_data = load_alarms(file_paths)
    
    print('Emitting update_alarms event with data:', alarms_data)
    socketio.emit('update_alarms', {'alarms': alarms_data})
    
class Watcher(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return
        if event.src_path.endswith('.txt'):
            logging.info(f'File modified: {event.src_path}')
            update_alarms_data()
            socketio.emit('file_change', {'action': 'modified'})
            
    def on_created(self, event):
        logging.info(f'File created: {event.src_path}')
        self.on_modified(event)
        
    def on_deleted(self, event):
        logging.info(f'File deleted: {event.src_path}')
        self.on_modified(event)
        
def start_observer():
    observer = Observer()
    event_handler = Watcher()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path=data_folder, recursive=False)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
    

@app.route('/')
def index():
    global alarms_data

    severity_options = sorted(set(alarm['Internal Severity'] for alarm in alarms_data))
    severity_counts = {severity: sum(1 for alarm in alarms_data if alarm['Internal Severity'] == severity) for severity in severity_options}
    
    return render_template('alarms.html', alarms = alarms_data, severity_options=severity_options, severity_counts=severity_counts)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    update_alarms_data()
    observer_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_observer, daemon=True)
    observer_thread.start()

    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5050, debug=True)

script.js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var socket = io.connect(window.location.origin);

    socket.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('Connected to server via WebSocket');
    });

    socket.on('file_change', function(data) {
        console.log('File change detected, refreshing the page...');
        location.reload(); 
    });


    socket.on('update_alarms', function (data) {
        console.log('Received update_alarms event', data);  
        const alarms = data.alarms;
        const alarmsTable = document.getElementById('alarms-table');
        alarmsTable.innerHTML = '';  

        alarms.forEach(function(alarm) {
            const row = document.createElement('tr');
            row.innerHTML = `
                <td>${alarm["Alarm ID"]}</td>
                <td>${alarm["Alarm Information"]}</td>
                <td>${alarm["Parameters"]}</td>
                <td>${alarm["Internal Severity"]}</td>
                <td>${alarm["Explanation"]}</td>
                <td>${alarm["Long Description"]}</td>
                <td>${alarm["Troubleshooting"]}</td>
                <td><a href="#" class="context-link" data-context="${alarm["Context"]}" onclick="filterByContext(event)">${alarm["Context"]}</a></td>
            `;
            alarmsTable.appendChild(row);
        });
    });
});

function filterAlarms() {{
    const idInput = document.getElementById('search-id').value.toLowerCase();  
    const textInput = document.getElementById('search-text').value.toLowerCase();
    const severityFilter = document.getElementById('filter-severity').value;
    const rows = document.querySelectorAll('#alarms-table tr');

    rows.forEach(row => {{
        const cells = row.getElementsByTagName('td');
        const idMatch = cells[0].textContent.toLowerCase().includes(idInput);
        const textMatch = Array.from(cells).some(cell => cell.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(textInput));
        const severityMatch = severityFilter === 'All' || cells[3].textContent === severityFilter;
        row.style.display = idMatch && textMatch && severityMatch ? '' : 'none';
    }});
}}

document.querySelectorAll('.context-link').forEach(link => {{
    link.addEventListener('click', event => {{
        event.preventDefault();
        const context = event.target.dataset.context;
        document.querySelectorAll('#alarms-table tr').forEach(row => {{
            const contextCell = row.getElementsByTagName('td')[7];
            row.style.display = contextCell && contextCell.textContent === context ? '' : 'none';
        }});
    }});
}});

function filterByContext(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  
    const context = event.target.getAttribute('data-context');
  
    const rows = document.querySelectorAll('#alarms-table tr');
  
    rows.forEach(row => {
        const link = row.querySelector('.context-link');
        if (link) {
            const rowContext = link.getAttribute('data-context');
            if (rowContext === context) {
                row.style.display = ''; 
            } else {
                row.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    });
  }

alarms.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Alarms</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.5.4/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/script.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Alarms</h1>
    <p>Here is the list of all alarms.</p>
    
    <label for="search-id">Search by Alarm ID:</label>
    <input type="text" id="search-id" onkeyup="filterAlarms()">
    
    <label for="search-text">Search by text:</label>
    <input type="text" id="search-text" onkeyup="filterAlarms()">
    
    <label for="filter-severity">Filter by Severity:</label>
    <select id="filter-severity" onchange="filterAlarms()">
        <option value="All">All</option>
        {% for severity in severity_options %}
            <option value="{{ severity }}">{{ severity }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Alarm ID</th>
                <th>Alarm Information</th>
                <th>Parameters</th>
                <th>Internal Severity</th>
                <th>Explanation</th>
                <th>Long Description</th>
                <th>Troubleshooting</th>
                <th>Context</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="alarms-table">
            {% for alarm in alarms %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ alarm["Alarm ID"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ alarm["Alarm Information"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ alarm["Parameters"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ alarm["Internal Severity"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ alarm["Explanation"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ alarm["Long Description"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ alarm["Troubleshooting"] }}</td>
                <td><a href="#" class="context-link" data-context="{{ alarm["Context"] }}" onclick="filterByContext(event)">{{ alarm["Context"] }}</a></td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div id="stats">
        <p>Total alarms: {{ alarms|length }}</p>
        {% for severity, count in severity_counts.items() %}
            <p>{{ severity }}: {{ count }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

</body>
</html>


I tried logging after everything SocketIO does and it sucessifully does everything until emit. Then the JavaScript file simply wont do anything in terms of SocketIO actions. It only executes this part of the code
socket.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('Connected to server via WebSocket');
    });

and the functions below for filtering which have nothing to do with SocketIO
